# How can I measure sub-second durations?

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, time

In my calculator-like program, the user selects what and how many to compute (eg. how many digits of pi, how many prime numbers etc.). I use `time(0)` to check for the computation time elapsed in order to trigger a timeout condition. If the computation completes without timeout, I will also print the computation time taken, the value of which is stored in a `double`, the return type of `difftime()`.

I just found out that the time values calculated are in seconds only. I don't want a user input of 100 and 10000 results to both print a computation duration of `0e0` seconds. I want them to print, for example, durations of `1.23e-6` and `4.56e-3` seconds respectively (as accurate as the machine can measure - I am more acquainted to the accuracy provided in Java and with the accuracies in scientific measurements so it's a personal preference).

I have seen the answers to other questions, but they don't help because 1) I will not be multi-threading (not preferred in my work environment). 2) I **cannot** use C++11 or later.

How can I obtain time duration values more accurate than seconds as integral values given the stated constraints?

Edit: Platform & machine-independent solutions preferred, otherwise Windows will do, thanks!

Edit 2: My notebook is also not connected to the Internet, so no downloading of external libraries like Boost (is that what Boost is?). I'll have to code anything myself.

Comment: You may be shocked to learn that there's more than one operating system that's used on all computers in the world, and that different operating systems provide different means of obtaining the current time, with various levels of precision. Unless you specify what O/S you're using, no authoritative answer will be possible, for pre-C++11 implementations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik edited. Sorry, I'm used to working on Java in school almost exclusively so I tend to be platform-independent on reflex. Still getting acquainted with C++ at work.

Comment: Considering that you want a platform independent solution, is there a reason you're avoiding C++11?

Comment: @Jason I just started work recently, and this is what I'm given for the time being. The project I'll soon be assigned to uses VC08, which to my understanding only has C++03, so might as well get used to it.

Comment: You should use the chrono facilities of C++11 and later. Otherwise, check if Boost has a high resolution timer. Most probably it has.

Comment: @thegreatjedi even in Java, there is no real "platform independent" solution, i.e. there is no one solution you can guarantee will work the same, exact way on any version of Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [QueryPerformanceCounter (QPC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is part of the Windows API to do high-resolution time measurements.

```
LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

// Activity to be timed

QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;


//
// We now have the elapsed number of ticks, along with the
// number of ticks-per-second. We use these values
// to convert to the number of elapsed microseconds.
// To guard against loss-of-precision, we convert
// to microseconds *before* dividing by ticks-per-second.
//

ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
```

Comment: Isn't this somewhat problematic, if the processor changes its frequency?

Comment: Well the documentation does say

`The frequency of the performance counter is fixed at system boot and is consistent across all processors so you only need to query the frequency from QueryPerformanceFrequency as the application initializes, and then cache the result.`

So it shouldn't matter but I'll be honest and say that I haven't dug that deep into it and took the documentation at it's word

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't look up the documentation myself and for some reason assumed it would be tied to the processor frequency.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, the simplest solution is to use `GetTickCount`, which returns the number of milliseconds since the computer was started.

```
#include <windows.h>

... 

DWORD before = GetTickCount();
... 
DWORD duration = GetTickCount() - before;
std::cout<<"It took "<<duration<<"ms\n";
```

Caveats:

- it works only on Windows;
- the resolution (milliseconds) is not stellar;
- given that the result is a 32 bit integer, it wraps around after one month or something; thus, you cannot measure stuff longer than that; a possible solution is to use `GetTickCount64`, which however is available only from Vista onwards;
- since systems with the uptime of more than one month are actually quite common, you may indeed have to deal with results bigger than 2<sup>31</sup>; thus, make sure to always keep such values in a `DWORD` (or an `uint32_t`), without casting them to `int`, or you are risking signed integer overflow. Another option is to just store them in a 64 bit signed integer (or a double) and forget the difficulties of dealing with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the compiler you're using doesn't support it, but for reference purposes the C++11 solution is simple...

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

long ts = std::chrono::duration<long, std::chrono::nano>(end - start).count();
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoting because I don't see why you should be downvoted. Even though it's not suited for my question in particular, it's still a useful reference that's good-to-know for all and is nonetheless relevant for what I imagine would be the majority - developers using the C++11 or later standard.

Comment: Only included for reference purposes.  Another solution is using `rdtsc` or `rdtscp` directly, but that's tied to the cpu.